# I want to merge the cognito user (mail/password) with google account user in'cognito'

Tags: oauth, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to link a user within 'Pre Signup Trigger' using adminLinkProviderForUser.
I can merge by setting the following in the parameter of adminLinkProviderForUser.

```
const params = {
  DestinationUser: {
    ProviderAttributeValue: username,
    ProviderName: 'Cognito'
  },
  SourceUser: {
    ProviderAttributeName: 'Cognito_Subject',
    ProviderAttributeValue: providerUserId,
    ProviderName: 'Google'
  },
  UserPoolId: userPoolId
}
```

But, I get an error when I try to merge the Cognito user (email/password) by first creating a Google account as follows.

```
const params = {
  DestinationUser: {
    ProviderAttributeValue: username,
    ProviderName: 'Google'
  },
  SourceUser: {
    ProviderAttributeName: 'Cognito_Subject',
    ProviderAttributeValue: providerUserId,
    ProviderName: 'Cognito'
  },
  UserPoolId: userPoolId
}
```

If I created a Google account first, is there a way to merge the cognito user (email / password) created later?

All the code currently written in Lambda. (I'm having trouble with the FIXME part.)

```
'use strict';

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const cognitoIdp = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
const getUserByEmail = async (userPoolId, email) => {
 const params = {
   UserPoolId: userPoolId,
   Filter: `email = "${email}"`
 }
 return cognitoIdp.listUsers(params).promise()
}

const linkProviderToUser = async (username, baseProviderName, userPoolId, providerUserName, providerName, providerUserId) => {
 const params = {
  DestinationUser: {
    ProviderAttributeValue: username,
    ProviderName: baseProviderName
  },
  SourceUser: {
    ProviderAttributeName: providerUserName,
    ProviderAttributeValue: providerUserId,
    ProviderName: providerName
  },
  UserPoolId: userPoolId
 }

 const result = await (new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   cognitoIdp.adminLinkProviderForUser(params, (err, data) => {
     if (err) {
       reject(err)
       return
     }
     resolve(data)
   })
 }))

 return result
}

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
 console.log(event)
 if (event.triggerSource == 'PreSignUp_ExternalProvider') {
   const userRs = await getUserByEmail(event.userPoolId, event.request.userAttributes.email)
   if (userRs && userRs.Users.length > 0) {
     let [ providerName, providerUserId ] = event.userName.split('_') // event userName example: "Facebook_12324325436"
     providerName = providerName === 'google' ? 'Google' : providerName
     await linkProviderToUser(userRs.Users[0].Username, 'Cognito' ,event.userPoolId, 'Cognito_Subject', providerName, providerUserId)
   } else {
    console.log('Users Not Found. This process skip.')
   }
 }
 
 if (event.triggerSource == 'PreSignUp_SignUp') {
   const userRs = await getUserByEmail(event.userPoolId, event.request.userAttributes.email)
   if (userRs && userRs.Users.length > 0) {
     // FIXME: This will be executed if the Cognito user is created later.I want to set parameters appropriately and merge with Google account users.
   } else {
    console.log('Users Not Found. This process skip.')
   }
 }
 
 
 return callback(null, event)
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm in the exact same situation and I'm thinking about manually creating a native user if one doesn't already exist when someone signs up using an external provider.

Answer (score 1):

According to the AWS documentation for the [AdminLinkProviderForUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminLinkProviderForUser.html#API_AdminLinkProviderForUser_RequestParameters) action, you cannot link a native Cognito email/password user to any existing user. Only federated users from external IdPs can be linked.

Definition for the `SourceUser` parameter:

> An external IdP account for a user who doesn't exist yet in the user
> pool. This user must be a federated user (for example, a SAML or
> Facebook user), not another native user.